# Looking for a working example of `SupportsRound`

Tags: python, mypy

There's not a lot of detailed information online about making type annotations work with `__round__`. I have implemented this but I still get an error on line 16 (calling `round` without an `ndigits` argument) when I run mypy:

> error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "int", variable has type "MyClass")

The test passes, i.e. in both calls to `round` I get back an object of type `MyClass`. But the MyPy check fails only when I call `round` without an argument.

Version numbers: Python 3.6.5, mypy 0.641.

```
from typing import Any, SupportsRound, overload

class MyClass(SupportsRound['MyClass']):

    def __round__(self: 'MyClass', ndigits: int = 0) -> 'MyClass':
        return self


def test_tmp() -> None:
    x = MyClass()
    result: MyClass

    result = round(x, 0)
    assert type(result) == MyClass
    result = round(x)
    assert type(result) == MyClass
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe the problem here has less to do with your use of `SupportsRound` and more to do with the definition of the `round` function. The `round` function is defined in typeshed, the repository of type hints for the standard library, to have [the following signature](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/master/stdlib/3/builtins.pyi#L914):

```
@overload
def round(number: float) -> int: ...
@overload
def round(number: float, ndigits: None) -> int: ...
@overload
def round(number: float, ndigits: int) -> float: ...
@overload
def round(number: SupportsRound[_T]) -> int: ...
@overload
def round(number: SupportsRound[_T], ndigits: None) -> int: ...  # type: ignore
@overload
def round(number: SupportsRound[_T], ndigits: int) -> _T: ...
```

Note that when only one argument is provided or `ndigits` is None, the output is always `int`. This is consistent with the documented behavior of the `round` function in the standard library: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round

Unfortunately, I don't see a really clean way of working around this: I don't think the [implementation of SupportsRound](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/master/stdlib/3/typing.pyi#L97) is really consistent with this behavior.

Specifically, SupportsRound probably ought to have been defined to be something like so:

```
@runtime
class SupportsRound(Protocol[_T_co]):
    @abstractmethod
    @overload
    def __round__(self, ndigits: None = None) -> int: ...

    @abstractmethod
    @overload
    def __round__(self, ndigits: int) -> _T_co: ...
```

Basically, force the user to handle these two cases.

Actually changing the definition would probably be complicated though: there isn't really a clean way of updating any older versions of Python that come bundled with older versions of the typing module.

I would recommend filing an issue about this on the typeshed issue tracker. I personally think you've discovered a genuine inconsistency/bug here, but there's possibly some nuance here that I'm missing, so I think it would be good to escalate this.